# convert data set to xml string

Tags: c#, xml

what i am trying to do is converting a dataset to an xml string. where t is returning me the output which contains the datasetname with datatable name . just i want to remove the datatable name and want to bind with only dataset node tag name. what should i do. here is my code.

```
if (sID > 0)
{
    String retXml = String.Empty;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtpdfAndEmailInfo = new DataTable("pdfandemailinfo");
    DataRow dr = dtpdfAndEmailInfo.NewRow();

    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Clear();
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("mailFrom", typeof(string));
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("mailTo", typeof(string));
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("mailCC", typeof(string));
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("mailBCC", typeof(string));
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("mailSubject", typeof(string));
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Columns.Add("salesorderpdfurl", typeof(string));
    ds.Tables.Add(dtpdfAndEmailInfo);
    dtpdfAndEmailInfo.Rows.Add(dr);
    String fileDirectory="D:\\po\\Sandbox\\po\\BOID_858_ORGID_571\\SalesOrderPdf\\" ;
    String FileName ="BOID_858_SOID_151382.pdf";     
    for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mailFrom"] = "someemailid@yopmail.com";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mailTo"] = "someemailid1@yopmail.com";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mailCC"] = "someemailid2@yopmail.com";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mailSubject"] = "Test";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(fileDirectory, FileName)))
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SalesOrderPdfURL"] = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SalesOrderPdfURL"] = "";
        }
    }

    Cmd.ResponseStatus.RowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    retXml = Util.GetXmlList(ds, "salesorderPdfAndEmailInfo", "pdfandemailinfos");
}

public static string GetXmlList(DataSet ds, String rootNode, String itemNode)
{
    return GetXmlList(ds, rootNode, @"cls=""dataArray""", itemNode, @"cls=""dataItem""");
}

public static string GetXmlList(DataSet ds, String rootNode, String rootAttribute, String itemNode, String itemAttribute)
{
    String rootNodeStartTag = String.Format("<{0} {1}>", rootNode, rootAttribute);
    String rootNodeEndTag = String.Format("</{0}>", rootNode);
    String nodeStartTag = String.Format("<{0} {1}>", itemNode, itemAttribute);
    String nodeEndTag = String.Format("</{0}>", itemNode);

    string retXML = ds.GetXml().Replace("<NewDataSet>", rootNodeStartTag).Replace("<Table>", nodeStartTag).Replace("</NewDataSet>", rootNodeEndTag).Replace("</Table>", nodeEndTag);
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(retXML);
}
```

and here is my response

```
"salesorderPdfAndEmailInfo": {
    "pdfandemailinfo": {
        "mailFrom": "someemailid@yopmail.com",
        "mailTo": "someemailid1@yopmail.com",
        "mailCC": "someemailid2@yopmail.com",
        "mailSubject": "Test",
        "salesorderpdfurl": "http://localhost/por/D:\\po\\Sandbox\\po\\BOID_858_ORGID_571\\SalesOrderPdf\\BOID_858_SOID_151382.pdf"
    }
}
```

what response i want should be like remove the datatable node tag name.any help will be apprecited.
response should be like this..

```
"salesorderPdfAndEmailInfo": {
    "mailFrom": "someemailid@yopmail.com",
    "mailTo": "someemailid1@yopmail.com",
    "mailCC": "someemailid2@yopmail.com",
    "mailSubject": "Test",
    "salesorderpdfurl": "http://localhost/por/D:\\po\\Sandbox\\po\\BOID_858_ORGID_571\\SalesOrderPdf\\BOID_858_SOID_151382.pdf"
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using the XMLSerializer? If your end goal is to have an xml representation of a dataset then I'd create an XSD. You can then use this to generate classes for serialization into XML.

Comment: Wheels73 is right. Create List<YouClassWithProperFields> then fill it with data and then just Serialize to XML using standart library

Comment: You have a jason string and not xml.  Use following to get an xml string :             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);